# eta: Layout does not render template body

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am currently implementing a web application using express and eta, and i am failing to include any kind of partial in my templates.

I tried to include a file partial ([Docs](https://eta.js.org/docs/learn/partials)) but the compiled template would not include the HTML contents of the included file.
I tried to define a partial in the singleton i created for eta beforehand as well.

`src/services/etaSingleton.ts`

```js
import * as eta from 'eta';
import { includeFile } from 'eta/dist/types/file-handlers';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';


class EtaSingleton {
    private static instance:any;

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
    private constructor() {}

    static getInstance(): any {
        if (!EtaSingleton.instance) {
            eta.configure({
                tags: ['{{', '}}'],
                views: __dirname + '/../views',

            });
            //console.log(readFileSync(__dirname + '/../views/incl/head.eta', {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'}).toString());
            //eta.templates.define('head', eta.compile(readFileSync(__dirname + '/../views/incl/head.eta', {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'}).toString(), {}));
            EtaSingleton.instance = eta;
        }

        return EtaSingleton.instance;
    }
}

export default EtaSingleton.getInstance();
```

I ended up using a layout instead

`src/views/incl/layout.eta`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>{{ it.title }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ it.body }}
    <footer>Copyright SomeCo, Inc.</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

`src/views/index.eta`

```html
{{ layout('./incl/layout') }}

<div id="content">
  Hello world
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshot, the contents of the template aren't rendered into the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to add the `=` sign to place data into the template ;).

So it should be `{{= it.title }}` and `{{= it.body }}` (or `{{~ it.body}}`, if it's HTML)